# Excel Add in Ribbon Gallery control

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2010, ribbon, excel-addins

I am looking for example on how to implement the ribbon gallery with Header intermediate (VSTO).

I am working on Excel Add-in in c# where gallery control is used, but how to implement or show items with groups as shown in image.

Each item are grouped with certain header.

[image: Ribbon Gallery]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible.

There are quite a few things like this in the Office ribbon: you can see that it can be done since the official Office ribbon has it, but there is no way to do it when developing. Two examples are the one you posted and in ribbon gallery (like the Chart styles in Excel).

Here is an similar question answered by one of the authors of the RibbonX book:
http://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?612-Menu-containing-galleries-and-menu-separators

Comment: This link, they have used menu control with separator and split button. But i need to replicate the functionality as above with any control menu or ribbon with rows and columns.

Comment: Read the first sentence. As far as I know it is not possible. The solution in the link is the closes you can get with the office controls.

Comment: Mitja, me too checked lot of links but why Microsoft has provided the control like this. Since that functionality will be useful for application where we need to show in categories, so that's why i asked help.

Comment: I have no clue why they decided to do it like this. You cannot do it via the existing controls in the office ribbon. So if you want functionality like that you will have to implement it on your own somehow.